# How Can I implement Dynamic Real Time Counter in Django

Tags: python, django, ajax

I have the following Django Models where I want to display real timer count down of the subscription (count down to the expiring Date) of every business account. I also have ajax code stored in my static/js folder where i referenced it on the base.html template. while in the index.html template I added a p tag with the countdown id but nothing is working. Someone should demonstrate the best way of achieving this in Django real time.

Models:

```
    class BusinessAccount(models.Model):
        STATE_CHOICES = [
            ('Benue', 'Benue'),
        ]
        LGA_CHOICES = [
            ('Gboko', 'Gboko'),
        ]
        ACCOUNT_CHOICES = [
            ('RICE MILL', 'RICE MILL'),
        ]
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        account_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ACCOUNT_CHOICES,
                                        null=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATE_CHOICES, null=True)
        lga = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=LGA_CHOICES, null=True)
        subscription_plan = models.ForeignKey(Subscription,
                                              on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def subscription_countdown(self):
            if self.subscription_plan:
                expiration_date = self.subscription_plan.expiration_date
                remaining_time = expiration_date - timezone.now()
                return max(remaining_time, timedelta(0))
            else:
                return timedelta(0)
     
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    class SubscriptionHistory(models.Model):
        business_account = models.ForeignKey(BusinessAccount,
                                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        plan = models.ForeignKey(SubscriptionPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        pin = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
        start_date = models.DateField()
        expiration_date = models.DateField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'Subscription for {self.business_account.name} \
            ({self.plan.name})'
My Ajax code in static/js folder:

<script>
  // Fetch the updated countdown value from the server
  function fetchCountdown() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/dashboard/', // Replace with your actual API endpoint
      success: function(data) {
        // Update the countdown element with the fetched data
        updateCountdown(data.countdownMillis);
      }
    });
  }
 
  // Update the countdown display
  function updateCountdown(countdownMillis) {
    var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');

    var days = Math.floor(countdownMillis / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((countdownMillis % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((countdownMillis % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((countdownMillis % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    countdownElement.innerHTML = days + ' days, ' + hours + ' hours, ' + minutes + ' minutes, ' + seconds + ' seconds';

    // Update the countdown every second
    setTimeout(fetchCountdown, 1000);
  }

  // Initial call to fetch the countdown value
  fetchCountdown();
</script>
```